# Not getting the expected proportion of epidemics of size 1 using fast_SIR

Tags: networkx, eon

I used fast_SIR to simulate 5400 epidemics, 30 each of my 180 networks of 1000 nodes. I did not state a node to start as initially infectious and therefore from my understanding it chooses a node at random as initially infectious. I calculated the expected proportion of epidemics of size 1 by considering cases in which the initial random infectious node does not transmit the infection to any of its neighbours. From my understanding the fast_SIR states that the time to transmission and recovery rates are sampled from the exponential distribution with rates tau and gamma respectively.

P(initial random node does not transmit to N neighbours) = sum_{N = 0}^{10} P(of N neighbours for initial node)*P(initial node does not transmit to a neighbour)^N

Where P(initial node does not transmit to a neighbour) is the stationary distribution for the initial node and is (transmission rate)/(transmission rate+recovery rate) = tau/gamma+tau = 0.06/(0.06+0.076)

I accounted for the probability that the initial random node is an isolated node since not all my networks are fully connected.

The actual proportion of epidemics of size 1 = 0.26 and the expected proportion of epidemics of size 1 using the above formula was 0.095

I don't know what I am not accounting for in the formula and what other scenarios or cases would lead to epidemics of size 1... Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know about the structure of your networks and haven't used this package at all, but a couple of thoughts that might be worth checking into if you haven't already:

Comment: 1. It looks like your first equation only sums the first 10 neighbors. Is that sufficient, or could there be some starting nodes that have more than 10 neighbors?
2. Isn't `tau/(gamma+tau)` the probability that a node **does** infect its neighbor, not the opposite?
3. Any chance of integer/decimal differences contributing to discrepancies? Simulation represents nodes as infected or not (1 or 0), but you can calculate continuous values. Hopefully not an issue once you've run enough simulations, but with such a small subset of outcomes that you're looking at, you never know!